# Intersecting objects loaded using FBXLoader— Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am loading an fbx file using FBXLoader. It's loaded successfully and added to the scene object. I want to get this object on click to apply transform controls. All the other objects are clickable except loaded through FBXLoader.

```
var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader( manager );
            loader.load( 'assets/models/fbx/iphone_ascii.fbx', function( object ) {
                scene.add( object );
            }, onProgress, onError );
```

Here is my intersection code:

```
onMouseDown(event) {
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
let rect = this.renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();

this.mouse.x = ((event.clientX - rect.left) / (this.viewportWidth)) * 2 - 1;
this.mouse.y = - ((event.clientY - rect.top) / (this.viewportHeight)) * 2 + 1;
let vector = new THREE.Vector3( this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y, 1 );

vector.unproject(this.camera);

let ray = new THREE.Raycaster( this.camera.position, vector.sub(this.camera.position).normalize() );

let intersects = ray.intersectObjects(this.scene.children);

if (intersects.length > 0) {
  if (this.activeobject !== intersects[0].object) {
    this.activeobject = intersects[0].object;
    this.transformControls.detach(this.activeobject);
    this.transformControls.attach(this.activeobject);
  }
}

this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);  }
```

Comment: Take a look at the `.setFromCamera()` method of [`THREE.Raycaster()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Raycaster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [THREE.Raycaster docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Raycaster.intersectObjects), note that `intersectObjects(objects, recursive)` takes a second parameter. Because models like FBX are often a collection of nested objects, you'll need to use the `recursive` option.

```
let intersects = ray.intersectObjects(this.scene.children, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But my requirement is to select whole group not it's children's.

Comment: You'll still need to check the children for intersections this way. Then you can use `child.parent` to select the parent rather than the child when the child is intersected.